# add the 8-bit signed magnitude binary numbers - binary arithmetic

Tags: math, binary, cpu-architecture, data-representation

I am trying to add 8-bit signed magnitude numbers: 10111000 + 00010111

```
  0   1 1 0 0 0 0 0        carry

  1   0 1 1 1 0 0 0        (-56)
+ 0   0 0 1 0 1 1 1      + (+23)
____________________     ________
      1 0 0 1 1 1 1   !=   (-33)
```

I know that the most significant bit (MSB) is the sign bit and should not be added. However, I am not getting (-33) as the answer in binary, and there doesn't seem to be an overflow also. I am not sure if I am doing it the right way. Please help.

Comment: Just because the MSB represents the sign does not mean it should not be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition in sign-magnitude representations is unfortunately not as straight-forward as with common complement representations. For sign-magnitude, you need to pick the correct operation based on the combination of signs. If you have equal signs, you simply add the magnitudes. If signs are unequal, you subtract the smaller from the larger and keep the sign of the larger magnitude. So, in your case:

```
  0 0 0 1 1 1 0        borrow

  0 1 1 1 0 0 0        (56)
- 0 0 1 0 1 1 1      - (23)
____________________ ________
  0 1 0 0 0 0 1   ==   (33)
```

Taking the sign of the larger magnitude (`56`) gives you the final number `1  0 1 0 0 0 0 1`.

Comment: So you are not considering the most significant bit at all?

Comment: Only at the beginning where we found that the two signs are not equal and thus need to subtract.

Comment: However, shouldn't the answer be -33, when you see the question, in decimal form the larger magnitude 56 has a negative sign, i.e., (-56) + (+23) = (-33), where the result takes the sign of the larger magnitude. Also, I still do not understand why you are subtracting, the question says to do an addition.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the signs of the two input numbers - corrected. The subtraction is there because this is how addition in sign-magnitude works - if you have equal signs, you add; if you have opposite signs, you subtract.

Comment: @SamVitare: Don't think of the sign bit as "most significant".  In sign/magnitude (unlike 1's or 2's complement) it doesn't *have* a place value.  Its meaning is as a modifier for the other bits.  Hopefully that's just a terminology problem and you only mean the left-most bit, at the highest bit-position.